# Can't use kiwi to install express framework

Tags: node.js

Hey guys,
I got the same error when I was using kiwi to install stuff, here's the error message I got when I was try to install express framework:

```
Agro:nodesynth Zhulin$ sudo kiwi install express
   install : express
   version : 
    create : /Users/Zhulin/.kiwi/current/seeds/express/
mkdir: /Users/Zhulin/.kiwi/current/seeds/express: File exists
     fetch : .seed
    unpack : /Users/Zhulin/.kiwi/current/seeds/express//express.seed
tar (child): /Users/Zhulin/.kiwi/current/seeds/express//express.seed: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
    remove : /Users/Zhulin/.kiwi/current/seeds/express/
rm: /Users/Zhulin/.kiwi/current/seeds/express/: Not a directory
Error: failed to unpack. Seed is invalid or corrupt.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NPM](http://npmjs.org/) instead, it's pretty much become the standard in package management for node.js. Kiwi hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: @Davejoe After I use NPM install express but I still got this error, it seems to still check the .kiwi folder, What should I do

Comment: Uninstall Kiwi, if that doesn't work then use the `npm bundle` command (assuming you have a package.json) and add `./node_modules` to node packages path.